# Creating a View popup over another ViewController on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I am trying to make some kind of popup view when a button i pressed on the iPhone. And it would be nice if I could manage that popup view with a ViewController. I have found out that the UIPopoverController could have been the solution, but it seems that it only works on the iPad...
But anyway, are there any similar solutions for the iPhone?
I am using storyboard

Answer (score 4):

Check out these repos on Github:

- https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover
- https://github.com/50pixels/FPPopover

Comment: Thanks for response, I will check them out when I have time. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Create a separate view controller and resize its xib file and make it look like a popup.
Then ADD this view controller as a subview, and also add it as childController too.

```
[self addChildViewController:self.popOverViewController];
[self.view addSubview:self.popOverViewController.view];
```

Now Make it hidden initially.

```
self.popOverViewController.view.hidden = YES;
```

If a user taps on Button then using fade in & Fade out animation you can hide/unhide it.
I can tell you how to fade in and fade out if you want to know it further, I hope you can do it easily.

Answer (score 2):

In interface builder make a UIView size of the screen and then make another in that Uiview with the style, size and the such for your pop over. Make its class, hook everything together.

```
CustomPopUpView *view = [[CustomPopUpView alloc] initWithFrame.....]
```

Add this all to your UIViewController with

```
[self.view addsubview:view]
```

Then attach a tapGestureRecognizer to the back view that animates the whole view off screen when tapped. So now if they click off your pop over view it close it will animates it off screen.

Hope this makes sense.

BooRanger